# pass parameter to click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a anonymous function from my jquery click event and I am trying to pass a parameter to it

How do I pass `u` into my click function `myobj.click(myOBJ.myfunc(u));`

---

```
myOBJ = {
    myfunc: function (evt, u) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert(u);
    }
}

var u = '2 is the lucky number';

myobj.click(myOBJ.myfunc(u));
```

Comment: why are you setting `u` to `2 is the lucky number` without quotes or a semicolon, you should check your console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass data to your event handler :

```
myOBJ = {
  myfunc: function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      alert(evt.data.u);
  }
}
myobj.click({ u: '2 is the lucky number' }, myfunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
myobj.trigger('click', myOBJ.myfunc, [u]);
```